# Symfony & Javascript, how deal with javascripts classes and extends?

Tags: javascript, oop

From symphony 4 and webpack encore, I created two simples statics classes A and B in two differents files ( B extends A ).

I want be able to call a function 'foo' from the class A which call a function 'faa' in the subclass B. And I need from the function 'faa' access to a static attribute of the class A.

File A : (./A.js)

```
const { B } = require("./B");

class A {

    static get _hello()   { return "hello all !"; }

    static foo(){
        B.faa();    
    }
}

module.exports = {
    A
};
```

File B : (./B.js)

```
const { A } = require("./A");

class B extends A{
    static faa(){
        console.log(super._hello);  
    }
}

module.exports = {
    B
};
```

When I execute this simple script : (./main.js)

```
const { A } = require("./A");
A.foo(); // must print "hello all !" but I get an error instead
```

I get this error "TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined"

I don't understand this error because I'm a beginner in Javascript OOP...
where is my mystake ?

Comment: Why does A need access to B, when B is the one extending A? I would expect static faa to be a method of A. As written, you have  a circular dependency chain.

Comment: yes, maybe my approach is not good. I have a mother and a child class, and I need use the mother class "alone" and the child "class" alone depending of context. And theses two classes must share some functions or attributes

Comment: in other words, how can I access to a function of a parent class when I have two classes in two differents files ?